# Eclipse says I have errors every day, but I don't

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This seems to be a problem with the on-the-fly code parser. As I am typing something, eclipse (latest release version) might update to reflect that I have an error. But when I finish typing the line, the error will still remain in the Problems tab and never get fixed, no matter what changes I make to that file or any other file. The only way to fix this problem is to go to Project->Clean... which of course works every time.

I use a rapid prototyping technique where I need to test my project hundreds of times throughout a day. This error happens about 10% of the time I want to run or debug a project, which is 10 times every day. Cleaning my project takes a significant number of seconds since we have hundreds of resources that need to be re-parsed. This is very frustrating and is killing my productivity. Is there any fix or patch to eclipse to fix this problem? If not, does anyone know of a workaround?

[image: Typical parse error that won't go away]

Comment: Did you check "Build Automatically"? that should clean all the errors you are seeing unless they are really compile time errors.

Comment: And hit CTRL-S (save) when you are done editing to trigger the automatic build.

Comment: What kind of resources?  In what language are you working?

Comment: Build automatically is checked. I'm using Java and coding for android with the ADT plugin. Ctrl+S doesn't trigger automatic build, or maybe it does but it says I have an error. If I look at the errors, they appear in the code window as red icons, every error is different but it is usually things like as I type an error is detected "function not found" then I add a variable in front of it to fix it, and I need to do full rebuild in order to get it to run (code is already now correct)

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project and hit refresh.  It usually works and is much faster than a full clean and build.

Comment: I'll try this as a workaround today, but I'm really looking for this to be solved automatically rather than requiring manual steps still.

Comment: I just tried it, refresh doesn't fix the problem. The error(s) still remain.

Comment: Hmm, this still happens every time I code in eclipse. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

can you please expand the errors ?

I guess this must be due to linking error.. 
ensure all the required jar are added, that should resolve.

Comment: Reproducing the error is usually quite easy. I just code normally. I have attached a screenshot of something after I type it. I cannot get rid of this error without cleaning.